# Why is an XML attribute without XMLNS prefix not equal to a prefixed attribute with same local name?

Tags: xml, w3c, xml-namespaces, xml-attribute

When the default namespace and a prefixed namespace resolves to the same namespace URI, why is an attribute with no prefix not equal to a prefixed attribute, when both have the same local name?

The "Namespaces in XML" specification just says it's so, but it's very short on why. **Anyone knows why it's like this?**

Excerpt from section "6.3 Uniqueness of Attributes" at http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/#uniqAttrs :

> For example, each of the bad empty-element tags is illegal in the following:
>
> ```
> <!-- http://www.w3.org is bound to n1 and n2 -->
> <x xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org" 
>    xmlns:n2="http://www.w3.org" >
>   <bad a="1"     a="2" />
>   <bad n1:a="1"  n2:a="2" />
> </x>
> ```
>
> However, each of the following is legal, the second because the default namespace does not apply to attribute names:
>
> ```
> <!-- http://www.w3.org is bound to n1 and is the default -->
> <x xmlns:n1="http://www.w3.org" 
>    xmlns="http://www.w3.org" >
>   <good a="1"     b="2" />
>   <good a="1"     n1:a="2" />
> </x>
> ```

I think this just makes it harder to parse namespaced XML, since the parser has to check the presence of both the attributes and pick one.

For my case, I like to add Atom links to my XML documents like this:

```
<root xmlns="..." xmlns:atom="...">
    <atom:link rel="self" type=".." href=".." />
</root>
```

I would think that the attributes on atom:link would inherit the elements namespace. Parsing the XML with DOM in Java reported the Atom namespace for the element, but no namespace for the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: unprefixed attributes are always in the empty name space, i.e. they have no name space.

In the example:

```
<good a="1"     n1:a="2" />
```

the first a would expand to

```
{}a
```

whereas the second would expand to:

```
{http://www.w3.org}a
```

In your atom example, all attributes are in the empty name space.

Comment: I stumble the same mistake today. But in that case, I don't understand why `<good ns2:a="1" xmlns:ns2="" />` is not allowed

Comment: Because `xmlns:ns2=""` is the way to undeclare the NS declaration binding using the `ns2` prefix and that would be in scope. Thus after having written that, the prefix `ns2` cannot be used. It is not bound to any NS.

Comment: Please note that the "empty NS" does not exist. It will lead to confusion if you think it exists. See [Namespace Myths Exploded](http://www.rpbourret.com/xml/NamespaceMyths.htm) by Ronald Bourret.