# Why is a namespace prefix being added to my XML attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-namespaces, xmltextwriter

[I have a fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zRyf0O):

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting");
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        var utf = new UTF8Encoding(false);
        XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stream, utf);
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        writer.WriteStartDocument();
        
        writer.WriteProcessingInstruction("process", "5");
        writer.WriteComment("commenting");
        
        writer.WriteStartElement("dog");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("attribute", "www.windward.net", "5");
        
        writer.WriteStartElement("cat");
        
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        writer.Flush();
        
        string result = utf.GetString(stream.ToArray(), 0, (int) stream.Length);
        Console.WriteLine("XML: " + result);
    }
}
```

I am adding an attribute with a no prefix namespace. It is creating a prefix of `d1p1`.

Why?

Comment: Please edit your post and add desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code-level answer

Because

```
    writer.WriteAttributeString("attribute", "www.windward.net", "5");
```

places `attribute` into the `www.windward.net`, and the namespace prefix is used to make the association.

If you want `attribute` to be in no namespace, remove the `"www.windward.net"` namespace argument:

```
    writer.WriteAttributeString("attribute", "5");
```

---

### XML-level answer

**Update to address OP comment:**

> What I want is for the attribute to have the namespace `www.windward.net`, but with no prefix. How can I do that?

That amounts to wanting default namespaces to apply to attributes, which is contrary to the [XML Namespace recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting):

> Default namespace declarations do not apply directly to attribute names; the interpretation of unprefixed attributes is determined by the element on which they appear.

If you want those attributes to be in a namespace, accept the API's use of a namespace prefix to put them there.

---

### See also

- [XML attribute names and elements in default namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11086899/290085)
- [XML namespaces and attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41561/290085)

Comment: What I want is for the attribute to have the namespace www.windward.net, but with no prefix. How can I do that?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7984397/11683, https://stackoverflow.com/q/41561/11683

Comment: @DavidThielen: Answer expanded to address your follow-up question.

Comment: Oh ok. That makes sense the way you explained it.

Comment: @GSerg: Answer updated to include the better of your two related Q/A links along with a another helpful Q/A link too.  Thanks.